# How to get the full definition of the HTML tag using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

To get the tag name in JQuery, we use:

```
     $(someCssSelector).prop('tagName');
```

This returns the tag name, e.g. 'DIV', 'TABLE'

How do I get the entire tag definition with all attributes, other than iterating over the element and getting each attribute's value? I need the text of the definition. For example:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="...." title="....">....</div>
```

Given the CSS selector for any element, I want to get, as string:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="...."  title="....">
```

The order of the attributes in the output string is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to check the element's `outerHTML`, and match the `<` to the `>`:

```js
const openingHtmlTag = $('#myDiv')[0]
  .outerHTML
  .match(/<[^>]+>/)[0];
console.log(openingHtmlTag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" style="color:green" title="foobar">content<div>
```

Or, in the somewhat unusual case that an attribute property can contain `>`s and escaped quotes, the regular expression needs to be expanded:

```js
const re = /^<(?:[^'">]*|(['"])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1)+>/s;
const openingHtmlTag = $('#myDiv')[0]
  .outerHTML
  .match(re)[0];
console.log(openingHtmlTag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" style="color:green" title="foobar">content<div>
```

https://regex101.com/r/OBNoBa/1

`^<(?:[^'">]*|(['"])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1)+>` means:

- `^<` - Start of string, followed by `<` (start of the opening tag)
- `(?:[^'">]*|(['"])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1)+` - Repeat 1+ times:

  - `[^'">]*` - Anything but quotes or an closing bracket, OR:
  - `(['"])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1` A quoted attribute:
  - `(['"])` - Opening string delimiter, first capture group. Then repeatedly match either:

    - `\\.` - Any escaped character (this allows, eg, `\'` to be matched, rather than the `'` being interpreted as the closing string delimiter), OR
    - `(?!\1).` - Anything but the string delimiter
  - `\1` - The string delimiter again (end of the quoted attribute)
- `>` - Closure of the opening tag

Another option would be to shallow clone the node (thus omitting any children it may have), take its `outerHTML`, and strip off the closing tag (which is a lot easier to match):

```js
const re = /^<(?:[^'">]*|(['"])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1)+>/s;
const cloned = $('#myDiv')[0].cloneNode(false);
const html = cloned.outerHTML.replace(/<\s*\/\w+\s*>$/, '');
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" style="color:green" title="foobar">content<div>
```

Comment: One cannot expect a more complete and perfect answer!